# 2 queries to 1 using 2 different WHERE

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT qurum_id, qurum, COUNT(qurum1) AS I FROM `qurum` AS qur
JOIN (SELECT id, qurum1,input_date FROM DATA ) `aa` ON qur.qurum_id = 
aa.qurum1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%Y') = $year AND DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') < 07

GROUP BY qurum_id
ORDER BY qurum_id
```

and

```
SELECT qurum_id, qurum, COUNT(qurum1) AS II FROM `qurum` AS qur2
JOIN (SELECT id, qurum1,input_date FROM DATA ) `bb` ON qur2.qurum_id = 
bb.qurum1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bb.input_date, '%Y') = $year AND DATE_FORMAT(bb.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 06 AND 12

GROUP BY qurum_id
ORDER BY qurum_id
```

How can I join these queries to 1? I need columns like this - qurum_id, qurum,  I, II.

Comment: You can use `union`

Comment: Store the output of both script in two different temp/var table and then use union.

Comment: I know, but how ? Could you write?

Comment: I don't think `UNION` is the best approach here for your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The trick is to take a conditional count of records depending on the month condition, which is different for your two current queries.  Note that the `WHERE` condition for the year was left alone, because both queries share this condition.

```
SELECT
    qurum_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') < 07
               THEN 1 END) AS I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 06 AND 12
               THEN 1 END) AS II
FROM qurum AS qur
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, qurum1,input_date FROM DATA ) AS aa
    ON qur.qurum_id = aa.qurum1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%Y') = $year
GROUP BY qurum_id
ORDER BY qurum_id
```